# OpenGL Vertex attributes not enabling

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

I'm trying to get some basic shaders working in OpenGL, and I seem to have hit a roadblock at the first barrier. I'm trying to enable some vertex attributes, but I'm getting weird results. I've brought up the draw call in RenderDoc, and only vertex attribute 0 is being enabled. Here is my VAO making code, and my render loop. I'm probably overlooking something really obvious. Thanks!

```
std::vector<float> positions;
std::vector<float> normals;
std::vector<float> texCoords;

for (auto x : model->positions)
{
    positions.push_back(x.x);
    positions.push_back(x.y);
    positions.push_back(x.z);
}

for (auto x : model->normals)
{
    normals.push_back(x.x);
    normals.push_back(x.y);
    normals.push_back(x.z);
}

for (auto x : model->texCoords)
{
    texCoords.push_back(x.x);
    texCoords.push_back(x.y);
}

GLuint indicesVBO = 0;
GLuint texCoordsVBO = 0;
GLuint vertsVBO = 0;
GLuint normsVBO = 0;

glGenVertexArrays(1, &model->vao);
glBindVertexArray(model->vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &vertsVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * positions.size(), positions.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glGenBuffers(1, &normsVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * normals.size(), normals.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glGenBuffers(1, &texCoordsVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * texCoords.size(), texCoords.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glGenBuffers(1, &indicesVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model->indices.size() * sizeof(uint32_t), model->indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

My Render Loop is this:

```
//I'm aware this isn't usually needed but I'm just trying to make sure
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);


for (GamePiece * x : gamePieces)
{
    glUseProgram(x->program->programID);
    glBindVertexArray(x->model->vao);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, x->texture->texID);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, x->model->indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT,(void*)0);
}
```

And my vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core



layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 outUV;
out vec3 outNormal;

void main() 
{
    outUV = texCoord;
    outNormal = normal;

    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
}
```

[image: RenderDoc Vertex Attributes not showing!]

```
#version 330

in vec2 inUV;
in vec3 normal;

out vec4 outFragcolor;

uniform sampler2D colourTexture;

void main() 
{
  outFragcolor = texture2D(colourTexture, inUV);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the fragment shader code,  Does it actually make use of the `outUV` or `outNormal1` values from the vertex shader?

Comment: Doing now. Normal isn't used, but UV is. I've actually found if I use the UVs as positions, they become the only attribute that is used, with render doc showing the only attribute as index 2 (texCoord)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [OpenGL 4.5 Core Profile Specification - 7.3.1 Program Interfaces](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf#page=117&zoom=100,168,690), page 96:

> [...] When a program is linked, the GL builds a list of active resources for each interface. [...] For example, **variables might be considered inactive if they are declared but not used in executable code**, [...] The set of active resources for any interface is implementation-dependent because it depends on various analysis and optimizations performed by the compiler and linker

This means that, if the compiler and linker determine that the an attribute variable is "not used", when the executable code is executed, then the attribute is inactive.
Inactive attributes are no active program resources and thus not visible in RenderDoc.

---

Furthermore the output variables of a shader stage are linked to the input variables of the next shader stage by its name.

`texCoord` is not an active program resource, because it is assigned to the output variable `outUV`. The fragment shader has no input variable `outUV`.

Vertex shader:

> ```c
> out vec2 outUV;
> out vec3 outNormal;
> ```

Fragment shader:

> ```c
> in vec2 inUV;
> in vec3 normal;
> ```

See [Program separation linkage](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Program_separation_linkage):

Either use the same names for the outputs of the vertex shader and inputs of the fragment shader, or use layout locations to linke the interface variables:

Vertex shader:

```c
layout(location = 0) out vec2 outUV;
layout(location = 1) out vec3 outNormal;
```

Fragment shader:

```c
layout(location = 0) in vec2 inUV;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
```

Comment: Given that fragment shader, why would the UVCoords be considered not used? Also I'm using opengl 4.5, so 4.6 wouldn't be affected by that change

Comment: @WillHain The specification for 4.5 and 4.6 is the same in that case.

Comment: Either way the UVs are used, so even if it's been made in active, why has it?

Comment: Ahh perfect. I did not remember that the shader variables have to be the same in each stage. Perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: @WillHain Alternatively you can use layout locations. See the answer.